# initializing an auto type variable to zero. Is this type safe?

Tags: c++, auto, type-safety

I'm relatively new to using the auto type, but I have been seeing it a lot in my code base at work lately.  One of the reasons I don't like using it is because I often forward declare things, which as far as I know cannot be done with auto. I was under the impression this was because types are determined at compile time.

What I am seeing a lot of is this, and I don't understand why you would ever do it.

```
auto value = 0;
if ( condition 1 )
{
    value = mValueStore.getValue(foo::bar::value);
}
else
{
    value = mValueStore.getValue(foo::bar::value2);
}
```

Is there a justification for doing this?

Comment: `value` will have the same type as `0`. It's no different then `int value = 0;`.

Comment: `auto` is not a type :)

Comment: If by *"forward declare"* you mean you declare your variables *way way* before needing them, then stop. There's plenty of reasons in C++ for which you'd want to avoid it.

Comment: `auto value = condition ? mValueStore.getValue(foo::bar::value) : mValueStore.getValue(foo::bar::value);`

Comment: Can you clarify your question, you asking is there justification of using `auto` vs `int` in this case?

Comment: That's one of the benefits. `auto` forces you to initialize the variables. The trick is to turn the initialization logic into a single expression, like a function call.

Comment: @mreff555 It's not clear to me what exactly you are asking about or what you are trying to achieve with the provided snippet.

Comment: Slava, yes, that would be another way of stating it.

Comment: in this particular case `auto` is used improperly IMHO. But using `int` would not be much better.

Comment: @nwp Or just `auto value = mValueStore.getValue(foo::bar::value);` seeing as both results are identical. Though that's likely a typo in the question.

Comment: nwp, I agree that this would be a much better solution to this code, however if there were many conditions this would not work.

Comment: @mreff555 then better solution would be using `std::result_of` but that is little bit verbose

Comment: @mreff555 Usually when I'm faced with something like that, I turn it into a function. Rather than `value = mValueStore.getValue(foo::bar::value);`, it'd be `return mValueStore.getValue(foo::bar::value);` inside a function, then I can have `auto value = myFunction(maybe, some, args);`

Comment: `auto` is not a type. It just means the compiler deduces the actual type for you from the initializing expression. The resulting variable still has a specific type - you just didn't have to type it since the compiler figured it out for you. But the end result is *exactely the same* as if you had written the type (in this case `int`) by hand. `auto` doesn't change *anything* type-safety-wise - it's just syntactic sugar that lets the compiler do some work figuring out the type so you don't have to, but the end result is the same.

Comment: The specific (pseudocode) example you give I'd probably rewrite as `auto value = mValueStore.getValue(foo::bar::value2);
if ( condition 1 ) {
    value = mValueStore.getValue(foo::bar::value);
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either using `auto` or `int` in this case is not perfect - because type of value is "disconnected" from the type that method returns. Probably `int` is little bit better in this case because type of `value` is clear, with `auto` it can give wrong impression. Better solution could be:

```
 decltype(mValueStore.getValue(foo::bar::value)) value = 0;
```

but that is verbose so even better using `auto` with conditional operator

```
 auto value = mValueStore.getValue( condition ? foo::bar::value : foo::bar::value2);
```

if possible to rewrite expression like that so `value` would always have the same type as that method returns.

Answer (score 2):

The drawback of using `auto` here is that it can somewhat give the impression of the type of `value` depending on the return type of `getValue()`. In fact, with `auto`, here, it is exactly the same as writing `int value = 0;`

If `getValue()` was to return a float, in the future maybe, one might be confused as to why `value` is not then a float.

The good thing of using `auto` is that you are force by the compiler to initialize it.

So, at the end of the day, depends on style and preferences.